# How to reactivate remote desktop service "No Machine" using command line?

Tags: remote-desktop

I wanted to connect to a Red Hat host with GUI. I have installed "No Machine" on that server. It worked perfectly. I got back to work a week later and the software is still installed but it no longer seems to work. I think I just need to run it again. The problem is that I don't have GUI access and I can't seem to find the instructions I previously used.

The question is:

How to run a NoMachine service from command line and check that it is running?

Answer (score 15):

From the command line you can issue the following commands:

to run the service:

```
/usr/NX/bin/nxserver --start
```

to check if it is running:

```
/usr/NX/bin/nxserver --status
```

to restart the service:

```
sudo /usr/NX/bin/nxserver --restart
```

Source:

https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/remote-linux-desktops-nomachine-nx/

Comment: Hi. I may be wrong but I think it would be with two dashes
`/usr/NX/bin/nxserver --start`

btw, how did you find that page? I googled it up cause I thought it was a no brainer to google it and did not see that page as a result on the first page. :)

Comment: The current link in March 2023 is [https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/remote-linux-desktops-nomachine-nx/](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/remote-linux-desktops-nomachine-nx/)